# Deploy a basic Java application to users in a network

Tags: java

I need some tips on creating a Java application. A few words about the application: **people in the company will log in with a pwd; customised access types; possibility to perform changes in a remote database from a host within the network.**

This is probably a very simple program. At first I don't care for security matters, that can be optimised in time. I just don't know how to start.

So far I've played with some algorithms (I like algorithms), connected an applet to a database and done a few select/updates, a couple of swings.

Even something that sounds like detailed chapter titles that I can investigate can prove useful, as I'm not sure what to look for when I want to create an application that can be distributed in a network.

Based on the previous:

1. **What do I need to create? An applet, a swing, etc? Should it be an .exe and how is that done roughly?**
   Thanks for any tips.
2. **I hear the application should come with an installation kit? What will that install - probably the JRE after checking whether it's installed on the client PC?** What else?

Other tips that I should know for starters?

I'm not worried about algorithms or class names in the context of a user action (a select/update,etc)- I can find those in libraries. I'm interested in how to actually create a basic application that can be sent to users all over the company (methodology/practices/trainings), that they can run and see on their screen the result of a simple select, let's say. Any pointers/good references - as there are a lot of sites out there and not all are good. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered Java Web Start to deploy a desktop application (which can use swing or Java FX 2 for example)?

Answer (score 3):

For Desktop Applications with a GUI and Database interaction etc. you should consider the use of a Rich Client Framework like [Netbeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/) or [Eclipse RPC](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform). This will certainly make a few things way easier, for example deploying the application, creating installers or multiple windows with docking capabilities. 
By the way

> At first I don't care for security matters

is generally a very, very bad idea...

Comment: Thank you! I like eclipse, been playing with it for a bit. GUI with database interaction, precisely what I am after. But what's the next step **to transform an applet into an application that can be ran by a user** on any network PC - (e.g. double click, visibility to his customised access via his user, and ability to change a remote db from a host from within the network); e.g. I lauched applets from within Eclipse but users don't normally have eclipse so I want a sort of a standalone application to give them

Comment: You can always wrap the applet in an application container.

Comment: Don't mix up Eclipse with Eclipse RPC that are two totally different things. Eclipse RPC just provides you with a framework to build your application, the users don't have to have Eclipse installed

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to launch the application from a web link?  Then what you're looking for is "JNLP" or "Java Web Start".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start

There are ways to set up user perms as part of the launch, and it will provision and deploy code and updates if necessary.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Paul! I need a desktop application. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: It will deploy desktop application using a web link, unlike an applet.